# Google Cloud Project does not exist (but should)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace

Before I start, I'm having the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46110125/cant-change-cloud-project-for-apps-script) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50484605/cant-switch-google-cloud-project-on-gas-editor). Unfortunately, neither of those solutions is working for me.

I have an add-on in the G Suite Marketplace. There are two separate entries, one for a Docs version and one for a Slides version. Now that the Chrome web store is being phased out for add-ons, I want to combine them into the same listing (afaik, that wasn't possible in the web store, only G Suite Marketplace).

Because of this, I now need to associate the Apps Script projects for both the Docs and Slides version with the same Cloud project. I'm hoping to migrate both to the Docs version because that has more users so hopefully fewer people will be impacted by the move.

I've taken the following steps:

1. Duplicate the Slides Apps Script project (to avoid messing with the original Marketplace listing until everything is set)
2. Go into the Cloud Platform settings for the new Slides App Script project
3. Enter the Cloud Platform project number for the Docs add-on

When I do this, I get an error that says "Project does not exist or you need edit access to it."

The weird thing is that if I try these steps to switch both projects to the Slides version in the Marketplace, it works. Because of this, I'm assuming there's some issue with the Cloud Platform project for the Docs version, but I can't seem to figure out what it is. Does anyone have any tips for common settings that could cause this error?

Comment: What happens if instead of duplicating the project you create a blank projecy and copy-paste your code manually? Keep in mind that if you set scope in the manifest files - you might need different scopes for and Docs Add-on than for a Slides Add-on.

Comment: @ziganotschka just tried that but unfortunately it didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion, though!
I'm thinking that if I can get this to work, the manifest files can stay the way they are since the apps script projects are separate. However, I'll need to update the OAuth consent screen since it'll need both.

Comment: A script has an underlying project that can be used only by that add-on, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects. Rather than moving the Slides add-on to the Docs one, create a new cloud project in the Cloud console and move both add-ons to that project.

Comment: @AlejandroTamalet I've seen that before, but I don't think that's the case for this project. I previously associated the Docs add-on with a project in the Cloud Console in order to publish it as an add-on (this can't be done via the underlying default project type). I can successfully move them both to the Slides cloud project, which makes me think there's some setting in the Docs cloud project that's preventing this. But I'm hoping to avoid using the Slides version or creating a new project to create the least amount of disruption for current add-on users.

Comment: So, if you open the appsscript.json file - does it contain the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents"?

Comment: @ziganotschka right now it's just auto-detecting the scopes from the code, so there aren't any scopes listed in the manifest file (for either the Docs or Slides version). The Marketplace SDK lets you specify separate Apps Script projects for the different apps, so I don't think the scope is an issue since I'm keeping these as separate Apps Script projects. I'm just hoping to associate them with the same Cloud project. This works if I make a new Cloud project from scratch or try to put them both in the Slides Cloud project, but I'm hoping to put them both in the Docs Cloud project.

Comment: I just thought that you copy pasted a script it might preserve the old automatically determined necessary scope and you might need to automatically redefine them. 
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/scopes
As for having different Apps Script projects in on GCP project - I have a Sheets and a Docs Addon in the same GCP project and it does not cause me any issues.

Comment: The copying and pasting was from Slides to Slides - I just made a copy because I didn't want to disrupt the Slides add-on that's already published. That's a good thought, though. Yeah it definitely seems possible. I can combine scripts into other GCP projects, it's just this specific one that's giving me an issue. I'm hoping there's some setting within the project that I'm missing or something.

Comment: The problem might be the recent change of the publishing requirements: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons So probably you will need to stick to publishing only one Addon per project.

Comment: I was wondering about that, but the Marketplace SDK lets you specify one script for each different G Suite App. Like I said, I can also combine multiple Apps Script projects into other Cloud Platform projects (including one GCP project that's already published). It's just this one GCP project that is giving me trouble, so I don't think it's related to this.

Comment: There's two type of projects, the ones you create and have full control of and the ones that Apps Script creates when a script is created. You can move scripts to projects you created but not to projects created by Apps Script. Did you create the project of the Slides script? One way to know is whether you can access it in the Cloud Console.

Comment: I did create both the original projects and they show up in the Cloud Console. I was able to post them into the G Suite Marketplace individually, and I don’t think that’s possible with the Apps Script-creates project. At this point I’ve officially given up and just combined them into the Slides version instead of the Docs version. But if anyone finds anything for future reference, I’d love to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and found out that it has something to do with the Shared Drive you have for a team.

Using the answer found by Ian: [Google Apps Script cannot convert from GAS managed to specific Cloud Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57692530/google-apps-script-cannot-convert-from-gas-managed-to-specific-cloud-project/61741136#61741136)

If the project is in a Shared Google Drive, like a team drive, you are no longer the owner (even if it says you are).

I couldn't create a new project in a shared drive and convert it to a Cloud Managed Project.

The only way I could do it was to create a new project on my account, in My Drive, and convert that to a Cloud Managed Project, THEN move it to the shared drive. (Once it is in a shared drive, you can't MOVE it back out.) However, if it is a Cloud Managed Project, you can add more scopes to the project after it is in the shared drive. - Once this new project is setup, then copy over your code for your old copy, and point all links to the new one.

Comment: Thanks! This one wasn’t in Shared Google Drive (in fact, the project that worked and the project that didn’t work were in the same folder). But hopefully this will help someone else with the same issue!